# Convert Set of arrays to one set in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a set of arrays

```
set1 = [[1,1,2,5],[4,3,5,9],[7,8,9,4,1]]
```

and I want to covert it to a single set so there is no duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of arrays. A [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) in JavaScript is a specific JS object type. *But* you *can* use a set to create a de-duped array.

First [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the nested array, and then pass that as an argument into a `new Set()`.

If you need an array again you can [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the set out.

```js
const arr = [[1,1,2,5],[4,3,5,9],[7,8,9,4,1]];

const set = new Set(arr.flat());

const newArr = [...set];

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `flat` method to combine the sub-arrays into one big array, and then create a set out of it to remove duplicates:

```js
new Set(set1.flat());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flat()` first then a function to remove duplicate elements from the array like this

```js
const set1 = [
  [1, 1, 2, 5],
  [4, 3, 5, 9],
  [7, 8, 9, 4, 1]
];

const result = set1.flat();

 function removeDuplicates(arr) {
   return arr.filter((item,index) => arr.indexOf(item) === index);
 }

console.log(removeDuplicates(result));
```

Comment: Your approach for removing duplicates work but you can also just create a Set from that array, which is a slightly simpler solution :)

Comment: True, but hey you always learn something new everyday, thanx for the tip